# Why doesn't the CSV parser exit the loop?

Tags: c#, loops, csv

I have a foreach statement which iterates through a CSV file and displays the fields which are in an array:

```
foreach (string line in lines)
{
    //MessageBox.Show(line);
    using (TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(textBox1.Text))
    {
        parser.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
        parser.SetDelimiters(",");
        while (!parser.EndOfData)
        {
            string[] fields = parser.ReadFields();
            foreach (string field in fields)
            {
                colArray.Add(field);
            }
            MessageBox.Show(string.Join(",", colArray));
            colArray.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```

My CSV has 5 rows, so what the above code is doing is displaying the messagebox from the first row to the last row and then goes back to showing the first row to the last row and continues to do it... How do I exit when the last row has been reached on the first iteration?

Comment: Have you attempted to use a CSV deserializer so you won't have to write this logic yourself?

Comment: I didn't no, unfortunately. First time trying to achieve it.

Comment: Are you implying that `parser.EndOfData` is never `true`?

Comment: Yes, it just keeps going :/

Comment: @MarioJVargas That's exactly what `TextFieldParser` is... it parses CSV data.

Comment: Why is your first line `foreach (string line in lines)` ? What is `lines` ?

Comment: I think that you know exactly what is going on. You just need to search why that property is not working like you expect. Maybe you are misunderstanding it.

Comment: `var lines = File.ReadLines(textBox1.Text);` and `textBox1.Text = '\\server\Cs\test.csv'`

Comment: How many strings are in the `lines` variable? For each of those strings, you're going to read the entire file and show one messagebox for each line in it. For each string. So if there's 5 lines in the file, that means 5 messageboxes. Then if there's 100 strings in `lines` that means 5 * 100 messageboxes.

Comment: You should try it out! I'm in a team that tried the same thing. I've played with [ServiceStack](http://mono.servicestack.net/docs/text-serializers/json-csv-jsv-serializers) before. My team is using `LumenWorks.Framework.IO.Csv` ([Code Project Article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader))

Comment: @Servy , I didn't know about `TextFieldParser`. Is this the one you're referring to `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser`? Hmmm... VisualBasic? :-)

Comment: @MarioJVargas: the `TextFieldParser`-class is the only "on-board" CSV-parser in the .NET framework. Do you really think that it's not working? I've used it often (both from VB.NET and C#).

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge : you realize that you are processing the CSV as many times as the lines number in your file ?

Comment: Looks like the problem is with while(!parser.EndOfData).  If it's never reaching parser.EndOfData, it will continue to restart the foreach loop over and over again.

Comment: @TimSchmelter , not sure why you concluded from my comment above that I don't think it works. I didn't say that. Period. After doing a quick google, my pet peeve is that it's in the [`Microsoft.VisualBasic`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx) namespace, which means unless you're using VB.NET and sticking to VB mentality, why do you want to use Visual Basic libraries? I've been in teams where they used VB libraries after a move to C# 4.0 (from VB.NET 1.1). We opted to remove any Microsoft.VisualBasic references for true System.*

Comment: @MarioJVargas Why?  What problem do you have with that particular class?  Nothing about it is VB specific.  And of course there's the fact that there is no counterpart in any non-VB library.  You're literally just complaining about the name of the namespace that it's in.  That's simply not a compelling reason to not use the type.

Comment: @Servy , I appreciate that you mentioned that class because, as I said, I didn't know about it. And I'm glad I'm aware of it now. It's up to an individual and a team to decide what their standards should be.

Comment: @MarioJVargas: there's no need to remove the `VisualBasic` namespace. It's just a class in the .NET framework, no more no less. In my opinion your team's priorities are wrong.

Comment: @TimSchmelter , back to the topic at hand. Using TextFieldParser is one way to solve a problem. By using a deserializer, such as the one I suggested earlier (that is, the one from ServiceStack since I don't know of others--I haven't done much CSV parsing myself), you can avoid having to iterate through rows and instead return a collection of "entities" (POCOs). That way you focus on addressing the business problem instead of attempting to solve a different problem first. That's why we have other serializers for different formats (eg. JSON.NET vs JavaScriptSerializer). I hope this is clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of this first line (as I said in my comments) :

```
foreach (string line in lines)
```

You will be doing the complete CSV processing (showing every fields of every lines) once per line in your CSV.

You probably want to remove this `foreach` loop.

**EDIT :**

You code *does* exit the `while` loop, and does exit the surrounding `foreach`, but only after a lot of useless iterations.

Answer (score 2):

Here is your code, in pseudocode form:

```
for each line in the file
  print out every single line in the file
```

This, understandably, prints out every line of the file more than once, although not infinitely many times.  It will print out every line in the file once for each line in the file.

To just print out every line in the file once, remove the outer `foreach`.